# How can I use a textbox value to set a value on a radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have in my model a property that defines the quantity to be inserted by the user.

To do that I use 3 radio buttons like this:

[image]
.

The code I use for this is the following:

```
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LabelsQuantity, "100", new { @class = "custom-control-inline radiobtn" }) @Html.Label("100", new { @class = "custom-label-inline " })
</div>
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LabelsQuantity, "1000", new { @class = "custom-control-inline radiobtn" }) @Html.Label("1000", new { @class = "custom-label-inline " })
</div>
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LabelsQuantity, "Other"  , new { @class = "custom-control-inline radiobtn" }) @Html.Label("Others", new { @class = "custom-label-inline " })
</div>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LabelsQuantity, string.Empty, new { @class = "custom-control-inline form-control enable_tb", type = "number", disabled = "true" })
</div>
```

The problem is that the value that I insert in the textbox isn't being passed to the controller, only the *other* string.

I need to be able to override the value in the view or to be able to get the value in the textbox in the controller.

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view model needs a 2nd property to bind the textbox to. The `DefaultModelBinder` only binds the first matching name/value pair, so it sees `LabelsQuantity=Other` in the request, and sets that to your `LabelsQuantity` proeprty, and ignores the `LabelsQuantity=ValueFormTheTextBox`.

Change the model to include an additional property, say

```
public string OtherQuantity { get; set; }
```

and bind to it in the view using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OtherQuantity)
```

You should also consider applying a conditional validation attribute, such as a [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[RequiredIf("LabelsQuantity", "Other"]` attribute so that you get client and server side validation

Note also that if the value of the textbox should always be a number, then you should make the property `int` rather than `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce another property for the `Others` text box that would post the value for it:

```
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LabelsQuantity, "100", new { @class = "custom-control-inline radiobtn" }) @Html.Label("100", new { @class = "custom-label-inline " })
</div>
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LabelsQuantity, "1000", new { @class = "custom-control-inline radiobtn" }) @Html.Label("1000", new { @class = "custom-label-inline " })
</div>
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LabelsQuantity, "Other"  , new { @class = "custom-control-inline radiobtn" }) @Html.Label("Others", new { @class = "custom-label-inline " })
</div>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Others, string.Empty, new { @class = "custom-control-inline form-control enable_tb", type = "number", disabled = "true" })
</div>
```

and in the model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string LabelsQuantity { get; set; }
    ...............
    ...............
    public string Others { get; set; }
}
```

and now in controller you would need to check if the radio button others is selected use the selected value provided in text box.